# Retrieve a date with Xpath

Tags: html, xpath

I have `<ul>`, and i want to retrieve all of the dates inside a href.

It looks like this

```
 <ul class="customSelectBoxList" id="BookingMenuCurrentMovieDay">
     <li class="current"><a href="#" data-showlistfilterdate="-1">What dat</a></li>
     <li class=""><a href="#" data-showlistfilterdate="21-12|20151221" class="">Today, mon</a></li>
     <li class=""><a href="#" data-showlistfilterdate="22-12|20151222" class="">Tomorrow, tue</a></li>
     <li class=""><a href="#" data-showlistfilterdate="23-12|20151223" class="">Wed 23/12</a></li>
     <li><a href="#" data-showlistfilterdate="31-12|20151231">Thu 31/12</a></li>
     <li><a href="#" class="disabled" id="AnnanDagRight" data-showlistfilterdate="-2">Other day</a></li>
</ul>
```

And i want to fetch all matches for example `<a href="#" data-showlistfilterdate="23-12|20151223" class="">Wed 23/12</a>` would be `20151223`.

And for this whole example it would be `20151221`, `20151222`, `20151223` and `20151231`.

**EDIT1**
This would be a query to fetch wed 23/12 for example

```
/html/body/div[@id='ShowListContainer']/div[@class='customSelectBoxContainer theme-csb']/
div[@class='customSelectBoxdisplayNone']
/div[@class='customSelectBoxListContainer']/ul[@id='BookingMenuCurrentMovieDay']/li[4]/a
```

**EDIT2**
This query (with substring-after) gives `null` results:

```
/html/body/div[@id='ShowListContainer']/div[@class='customSelectBoxContainer theme-cab']
/div[@class='customSelectBox displayNone']
/div[substring-after(//ul[@id="BookingMenuCurrentMovieDay"]/li/a/@data-showlistfilterdate, "|")]
```

Maybe i have misplaced substring-after()?

Comment: what this has to do with php, why php is tagged in this question ?

Comment: @MeeneshJain fixed that. Good point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perfect use-case for [`substring-after()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/substring-after):

```
substring-after(//ul[@id="BookingMenuCurrentMovieDay"]/li/a/@data-showlistfilterdate, "|")
```

Comment: Thanks! But I can't get it to work.. Is it okey if i update my first post with more info?

Comment: @Adam well, the problem is that, for some reason, you are putting the `substring-after()` call into the `div[]`. Could you check exactly the expression I've provided? Thanks.

Comment: The Xpath helper says `Results(1)`, but doesn't show anything.

Comment: @Adam yeah, I think I got what are you trying to say. This would, for instance, work: `substring-after((//ul[@id="BookingMenuCurrentMovieDay"]/li/a/@data-showlistfilterdate)[2], "|")`, right?